# Python/PyGame How can I check if a rect is directly above or beside another rect in all four directions?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with Python and PyGame and I would like to implement a sight line system where enemies can detect you when you're within the length or width of them (they are Rects). What is the most effective way to check this? This is what I have if it's any help...

```
class FOV:
def view_left_top(ax,ay,bx,by,bh):
    return ax < bx and ay < (by + bh) and ay > by

def view_left_bottom(ax,ay,ah,bx,by,bh):
    return ax < bx and ay < (by + bh) and (ay + ah) > by

def view_right_top(ax,ay,aw,bx,by,bw,bh):
    return ax + aw > bx + bw  and ay < (by + bh) and ay > by

def view_right_bottom(ax,ay,aw,ah,bx,by,bw,bh):
    return ax + aw > bx + bw  and ay < (by + bh) and (ay + ah) > by

def view_top_x(ax,ay,bx,by,bw):
    return ay < by and ax > bx and ax < (bx + bw)

def view_top_y(ax,ay,aw,bx,by,bw):
    return ay < by and (ax + aw) > bx and ax < (bx + bw)

def view_bottom_x(ax,ay,bx,by,bw):
    return ay > by and ax > bx and ax < (bx + bw)

def view_bottom_y(ax,ay,aw,bx,by,bw):
    return ay > by and (ax + aw) > bx and ax < (bx + bw)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pygame.Rect.colliderect(Rect) method to test if two rectangles overlap.

```
import pygame

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)  #x, y, width, height
    def update(self, screen, entities):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), self.rect)  #Draws red square

        for e in entities:
            if self.rect.colliderect(e.rect):
                is_colliding = True
                break
            else:
                is_colliding = False
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I have the collision detection handled but what I'm looking for is whether the Rect is passing IN FRONT OF the other Rect. Although what you gave me for collision detection is much more efficient than what I had so props to you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up managing to at least clean it up a bit by combining some of those functions into a single function and an 'if' statement